# containers flowing out of the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have provided the link of the image just below, in the image, the containers are moving out of the screen .i.e overflowing to right side. I want only 3 containers should occupy a single row and the remaining should move on to next row and when I decrease the width of the screen than 2 containers should occupy 1 row. Here, container means div with className
"Restaurant1"

[image: Image of current problem]

```css
.Section_Offers_Near_You {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #3d4152;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.Resturants {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Resturant1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div className="Section">
  <div className="Offers">
    <div className="Offer__Sidebar">
      <div className="Offers_Near_You">
        <img className="Offer__img" src={offersNearYou} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>Offers Near You</div>
          <p>211 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Top_Picks">
        <img className="Offer__img" src={topPicks} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>Top Picks</div>
          <p>58 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Whats_New">
        <img className="Offer__img" src={whatsNew} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>What's New</div>
          <p>32 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Vegeterian_Options">
        <img className="Offer__img" src={vegeterianOption} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>Vegeterian Options</div>
          <p>455 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="See_All">
        <img className="Offer__img" src={seeAll} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>SEE ALL</div>
          <p>866 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="Section_Offer_Restuarants">
      <div className="Section_Offers_Near_You">Offers Near You</div>
      <div className="Resturants">
        <div className="box">
          <div className="Restaurant1">
            <img className="Restuarant_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_508,h_320,c_fill/brepli1v2r2kqtfi3voi" />
            <div className="Name">Belgian Waffle</div>
            <div className="Food_Details">Desert, Bakery, Beverages</div>
            <div className="Details">
              <div className="Rating">
                <StarIcon className="Icon" /><span>4.2</span></div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="Time">44 MINS</div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="People">₹250 FOR TWO</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="discount">
              <img className="discount__img" src={discount} />
              <p>60% off | Use TRYNEW</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="Restaurant1">
            <img className="Restuarant_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_508,h_320,c_fill/brepli1v2r2kqtfi3voi" />
            <div className="Name">Belgian Waffle</div>
            <div className="Food_Details">Desert, Bakery, Beverages</div>
            <div className="Details">
              <div className="Rating">
                <StarIcon className="Icon" /><span>4.2</span></div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="Time">44 MINS</div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="People">₹250 FOR TWO</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="discount">
              <img className="discount__img" src={discount} />
              <p>60% off | Use TRYNEW</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="Restaurant1">
            <img className="Restuarant_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_508,h_320,c_fill/brepli1v2r2kqtfi3voi" />
            <div className="Name">Belgian Waffle</div>
            <div className="Food_Details">Desert, Bakery, Beverages</div>
            <div className="Details">
              <div className="Rating">
                <StarIcon className="Icon" /><span>4.2</span></div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="Time">44 MINS</div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="People">₹250 FOR TWO</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="discount">
              <img className="discount__img" src={discount} />
              <p>60% off | Use TRYNEW</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="Restaurant1">
            <img className="Restuarant_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_508,h_320,c_fill/brepli1v2r2kqtfi3voi" />
            <div className="Name">Belgian Waffle</div>
            <div className="Food_Details">Desert, Bakery, Beverages</div>
            <div className="Details">
              <div className="Rating">
                <StarIcon className="Icon" /><span>4.2</span></div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="Time">44 MINS</div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="People">₹250 FOR TWO</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="discount">
              <img className="discount__img" src={discount} />
              <p>60% off | Use TRYNEW</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="Restaurant1">
            <img className="Restuarant_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_508,h_320,c_fill/brepli1v2r2kqtfi3voi" />
            <div className="Name">Belgian Waffle</div>
            <div className="Food_Details">Desert, Bakery, Beverages</div>
            <div className="Details">
              <div className="Rating">
                <StarIcon className="Icon" /><span>4.2</span></div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="Time">44 MINS</div>
              <div className="dot">•</div>
              <div className="People">₹250 FOR TWO</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="discount">
              <img className="discount__img" src={discount} />
              <p>60% off | Use TRYNEW</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS or frameworks to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the property `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container to let these elements go to the next row when there isnt enough space:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: add an empty element to the end to fix the issue with uneven amount of elements. This will not break or change the layout when you have even for example 4 since it doesnt has any height

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mithilesh Patil i edited the answer with a solution